# Will awarding bounties remove privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, privileges

If I award a bounty, and my rep therefore goes lower, do I lose the privileges I've earned? For example, if I was just at 1001 Rep, and put up a bounty for 50 Rep and awarded it, do I lose my privileges for having 1000 rep? Or does it stay there since I did eventually earn it?

Comment: The minimum bounty is 50, AFAIK.

Comment: Edited. Thanks. I haven't given a bounty, so I never checked. I was scared of losing brand new privileges

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Privileges are *not* permanent.**

If your rep falls below the required threshold of a privilege for *any* reason (you place a bounty, downvotes, rep recalc, beta→gold site transition, etc) you do lose the privilege, but only until your rep increases above the required threshold again.

Comment: They should change that. Currently I would like to put a bounty on one of my questions yet by doing that I would look access to lots of privileges. Privileges should be based on life time total rep instead of current rep.

Comment: I agree. They should differentiate between reputation lost from offering a bounty vs. downvotes etc.